# An error has occurred. 0 The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform.

Tags: joomla

after manually updating from Joomla 3.51 to Joomla 3.6 my website works without any problems, but when I try to reach my administraton zone i get anerror "An error has occurred. 0 The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform. " anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 9):

Check that `tmp` and `cache` directories are writable by the server.
I had the same issue after update to `Joomla 3.6`

Comment: In addition to belkas' answer above, make sure the cache directory under the administrator directory is also writable by the server

Comment: thanks a lot to you both @belka and Dabblernl. I am not a php guy, even I fixed it :) One question. After giving these all permission, is everything safe?

Comment: just observed that my site is up but <website>/administrator is down. showing *500: Internal Server Error*. Plz help.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran, check also administrator/cache. If only cache directories are writable, it should be safe.

Answer (score 6):

In `configuration.php`, replace `$cache_handler` with `$cachelite`.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a known issue, and I could've sworn I have answered this particular question myself. The Joomla developers state that this is should be the expected behavior when there is an issue with the cache adapter (most likely this issue is a permission issue on the `cache` folder or the `administrator/folder` - they are not writable by Apache).

We have discussed the issue at length [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/the-file-cache-storage-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-error-after-updating-to-joomla-3-6) - and it has sparked a Twitter discussion on whether this is a feature or a bug. The Joomla development team insists it is a feature that was added for stability reasons (see their reply [here](https://michaels.website/blog/joomla-36-cache-changes)) - despite the fact that the previous behavior did not cause the whole Joomla website to crash (the current behavior does).

The fix is typically simple and it almost always consists of making both the `cache` and the `administrator/cache` folder as writable by Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The following setting should fix your issue.

(1) Go to your Files and find the **configuration.php**

(2) Open **Configuration.php** and locate public **$cache_handler = 'file';**

(3) change **public $cache_handler = 'file';** to  **public $cachelite = 'file';**

(4) **Save** the file.